# Count current and longest streak from null or 1 values

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm trying to count longest and current streak from null or 1 values in google sheets.

It's going to be used in Data Studio, but I have to make calculation in Sheets.

I've tried a sultion from below post, but it's nor working for me and also I have null values not 0, and it has to stay this way (rows in sheet are being appended from google forms form, where I check whether I did a habit or not).
[Google Sheets - How to count streaks of non-zero numbers on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284216/google-sheets-how-to-count-streaks-of-non-zero-numbers-on-one-column)

Please help if you can, thanks before

Here is the spreadsheet with some example data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GaaEJ24ERulPftYAILOuokY929HInkh-SjAJUEvrW5M/edit?usp=sharing

[values to visualize in streaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMa5z.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear what you mean by "current streak". Consider showing your _manually entered_ desired results in the sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the longest streak in data:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(join(""; Data!A1:A)); 
    max( len( split( 
      concatenate( left(isblank(Data!A1:A)) ); 
      "T" 
    ) ) ); 
    "no streak" 
  ) 
)
```

And this to get the last streak in the data:

```
=+sort( 
  if( 
    len(join(""; Data!A1:A)); 
    len( transpose( split( 
      concatenate( left(isblank(Data!A1:A)) ); 
      "T" 
    ) ) ); 
    "no streak" 
  ); 
  sequence( rows( 
    transpose( split( 
      concatenate( left(isblank(Data!A1:A)) ); 
      "T" 
    ) ) 
  ) ); 
  false 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GaaEJ24ERulPftYAILOuokY929HInkh-SjAJUEvrW5M/edit#gid=105564853).

Answer (score 0):

### longest:

```
=INDEX(COLUMNS(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(IF(A1:A=""; 0; "×");;9^9)); " 0 "; )); " ")))
```

[image]

---

### all:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(A1:A=""; "×"; "¤");;9^9); "×"; ))); " "; )); 
 "where Col1 <> 0"))
```

[image]

---

### last:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SORT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(A1:A=""; "×"; "¤");;9^9); "×"; ))); " "; )); 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A)-COUNTA(A1:A)); 0); "where Col1 <> 0 limit 1"; ))
```

[image]