# How to Count Winning Streak when Player Does Not Play?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count a win streak in google sheets by counting the number of ones in a row (1).

Here is the current formula that I am using:

```
=sortn(frequency(if((M2:M=1)*len(M2:M),row(M2:M)),if((M2:M=1)*len(M2:M),,row(M2:M))),1,0,1,0)
```

It works great, but unfortunately the win steak ends if a player does not play (DNP). So if one of those rows does not have a 1 in the Win, and it is blank, then the win streak is over.

I would like the win streak to include blank rows too if possible. Any suggestions on how I can update this formula, so my win steak does not end with a blank value?

Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer. =)

[image]

Just to add a litte more clarity: Right now if I have ten "1"s in a row, but the fifth row does not have any data (DNP) then my win streak would only be 5.

This is the output that I would like below:

[image]

Here is an example of the recent output suggested:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with test data and expected output(*manually entered*) so as to get a clear picture to work it out

Comment: @rockinfreakshow is there an easy way to do that on here?

Comment: From the [tag:google-sheets] tagwiki: *Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.* There is no way to post a sheet here directly, as SO does not allow attachments.

Comment: Your table shows `Win streak = 10`, but you just finished saying that a DNP ends a streak. So isn't winning streak = 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets - How to count streaks of non-zero numbers on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284216/google-sheets-how-to-count-streaks-of-non-zero-numbers-on-one-column)

Comment: Yes sir @Tedinoz. A DNP currently does end the Win streak... but I do not want the Win streak to end.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not feel that answers my question.

Comment: Hi @AbleArcher I have suggested a solution. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: `Unfortunately I do not feel that answers my question` I _do_ understand why you might respond in this way. Many questions have concepts or processes in common, but may not "exactly" reflect a certain scenario. OTOH, @Logan recognised the process that was applicable to your scenario, and their answer is, I think, a good adaptation of that question. I'll withdraw the "duplicate" reference but I commend Logan's answer to you as a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion:

From your sample, I have figured that it was unnecessary to use other columns if you will just leave it blank. And also it makes it much more difficult to track the streaks using formulas. I suggest using only 1 column for the Win/Lose status where 1 = Win and 0 = Loss, and use the following formula:

**Try:**

```
=INDEX(COLUMNS(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(A2:A,,9^9)), " DNP ", " " ), "0", )), " ")))
```

**Result:**
[image]

From the posted comment of Tedinoz linking to :
[How to count streaks of non-zero numbers on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284216/google-sheets-how-to-count-streaks-of-non-zero-numbers-on-one-column).
I have modified the accepted answer to replace the DNP with blank so it will continue to track the win streak.

Comment: Hello @Logan, this formula looks correct at first glance but did not give the correct consecutive win streak. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hi @AbleArcher apologies if this did not resolve your concern. Can I see a sample where it's not giving correct result? I can try to modify the formula

Comment: No problem at all brother. Sorry for the late response. I will post an example now.

Comment: @AbleArcher From your sample, I have updated the formula in the posted answer. Please see if this works for you now I only changed the `" 0 "` to `"0"`. Here's the updated formula: `=INDEX(COLUMNS(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(A2:A,,9^9)), " DNP ", " " ), "0", )), " ")))`

Comment: Brilliant @Logan! Thank you very much for taking the time to help. So grateful =) Spent so much time on this problem.